# Two lines, random point and vector. How to find which line is located behind other one

Tags: math, vector, line

I am developing a game, where player must walk in dark corridors. Character has a torchlight and camera is located above (like in GTA2).I have problem with shading algorithm.

[image]

So we have a light source(yellow cyrcle),bunch of walls(green and blue lines) and light vector(red arrow).
What we know:
- distance between light source and lines;
- length of lines;
- light vector coordinates;
- lines are NOT crossing with each other;
- angles of line endpoints;

Question:
How to make program see which line lies IN FRONT of other lines? For 
example, in image we can see that green line is in front of blue line.

We could find a crosspoints of a vector and a both lines, then find length between lightsource and crosspoints and compare them to find the closest line, however it will slow down the program. Moreover, a situation may occur, where blue line will be closer to light source(if we move a light source a little upper), however program must still see that blue wall is located BEHIND green line.
Maybe we could somehow mark every line with some value?

**EDIT :** I also tried to create a value for every line by using formula: a/alpha + b/beta
Where:
a - distance between light source and first endpoint of a line
alpha - angle of first endpoint of a line
b - distance between light source and second endpoint of a line
beta - angle of second endpoint of a line
One of the angles must be reverted.

But in order this formula to work, it seems there must be some constant, example:
a*const/alpha + b*const/beta
Maybe by finding this constant I can give every line a value?

Comment: Those calculations will no slow the program down much, if you do them only for the line endpoints. I don't understand the "moreover" problem; the light vectors through the endpoints (or any vectors that pass through both lines) will pass through green first.

Comment: @Beta, it means that if light vector will reach green line it will stop right there and will not reach blue line behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

> The blue line is behind the green line.

is equivalent to the statement

> There is a ray from the light source that passes through the green line and then the blue line.

(Note that this is a mathematical ray, not a light ray-- it passes through blue and green obstacles.)

This is equivalent to

> There is a ray from the light source that intersects both lines, and the green intersection is closer to the light source than the blue one is.

Searching for such a ray looks difficult at first, -- there are infinitely many to test -- but I argue that if such a ray exists, then there must be such a ray that passes through one of the line endpoints. Now there are only four to test.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer. Actually, we have rays that connect both endpoints of intersections. We also know the distance from beginning of rays to endpoints. And the angles of the endpoints. Can this information somehow help to solve this?

Comment: @Olich: "Rays that connect both endpoints of intersections"? What does that mean?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I meant that rays connect both endpoints of a line.

Comment: @Olich: So you have four such rays. One of them must also intersect the other line (otherwise neither line is behind the other). Considering that ray, you have the distance from the light source to the endpoint of one line, and you can calculate the distance from the light source to the other line (along that ray). Compare those distance and you're done.

Comment: I thought about it, however there will be a lot of calculations which can slow down the game. And what can we do, if we have a ray, that is NOT connected to endpoints(like in the picture above)? Program must somehow 'realise' that ray reached green wall and he cannot go through it.

Comment: @Olich: Are you interested in that ray alone? Or in which line is behind the other? You will not be able to solve this problem without *some* calculation.

Comment: I am interested in which line will be crossed first by that red ray - the green or the blue one

Comment: @Olich: **Use the solution I have given you**, to determine which line is behind the other. Then if the blue one is behind the green, the red ray will reach the green first; if the green one is behind the blue, the red ray will reach the blue first.